# Input on Vue For-Loop Generated Component Loses Focus when Order Changes

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, input, focus

I am rendering Vue components like:

```
<component v-for="item in sortedItems()" v-bind:key="item.id" :item="item"></component>
```

The components are sorted alphabetically according to `item.title`:

```
// Returns a sorted copy of this.items
sortedItems: function() {
    return [...this.items].sort((a, b) => (a.title >= b.title ? 1 : -1));
}
```

Each component has an input element with `v-model="item.title"`. When I edit the title and it causes the items to be re-ordered, the input loses focus.

Each component has a unique key so I'm not sure why the input loses focus. Maybe the component is being destroyed and recreated?

I'm fairly new to Vue and all other posts about this issue just tell me to have a unique key when using v-for, which I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Using `v-model.lazy` in place of `v-model` works for me here. This causes the model to only update after the input loses focus. So, the titles of my items list don't change while the input still has focus and they won't be resorted until focus is already lost.